# Unable to find a way to sync an existing Shared Calendar in outlook to Sharepoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online

is it possible to sync an existing shared calendar in outlook to Sharepoint online site? I am aware of the way to connect a Sharepoint calendar back to Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to get this done, the sync is not supported for SharePoint online. Also the overlay calendar for Exchange doesn't work in SPO( Exchange calendar issue) All you can do is build AAD app use outlook/Graph APIs get the information from Outlook and display it in SharePoint ([Check this blog](https://codeatwork.wordpress.com/2017/04/16/using-outlook-rest-apis-in-sharepoint-online/)). If you want to display it in Calendar view you will have to use plugins like Full calendar to do that.